# Jquery или JavaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вопрос таков, если например, ты можешь сделать, какую-то функцию на нативном JavaScript и на Jquery. Что, лучше выбрать?

Например

1)

```
  function toltipImg(){
       var el = document.getElementById("picture1")
       el.onmouseover = toltipUpImg;
       el.onmouseout = toltipDownImg;
  }
```

2)

```
  function toltipImg(){
        $("#picture1").hover(toltipUpImg, toltipDownImg)
   }
```

Comment: Зависит от того к чему привыкли :) Это уже эстетический выбор))

Comment: а по скорости? как там

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если ЭТО — единственная функция, которую вы собираетесь использовать на JQuery, то нет смысла. JQuery — лишь библиотека, позволяющая сократить самописный код и дающая какие-никакие условия кроссбраузерности. Но для выполнения загружается-обрабатывается-выполняется вся библиотека.

Comment: не я просто привел пример, мне интересно по скорости, вроде быстрее будет работать на нативном?

Answer (score 0):

нативная, `javascript` быстрее.